# swift не понятно, что за ошибка

Tags: swift

В плейграунде возникает вот такого типа ошибка

> Use of 'self'in method call 'rand' before all stored properties are
>   initialized

и ниже

> Return from initializer without initializing all stored properties

код ниже

```
class engine {

      // Главные настройки игры

      // игра закончена да/нет
      var gameFinished = false

      // Генератор случайных чисел
      func rand(minNum: Int, maxNum: Int) -> Int {
            let rand = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(maxNum-minNum)) + 1) + minNum
            return rand
      }

      init() {
            if self.rand(1, maxNum: 1000) > self.rand(1, maxNum: 1000) {
                  self.oddeven = true
            }
      }

      var myVar: String 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Вопрос решен.

Проблема была в том, что в классе есть не инициализованные переменные,
по этому и возникла проблема